# Vuex: unknown action type in nuxt js

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

I using auth service of firebase. I have a problem when I calling the action from vuex. Currently I trying only login but I taking this error: Vuex: unknown action type. You will see in method, I tried ("namespace/users") but not solve it. Can someone help me? please.

users/index.js (in store folder)

```
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "@/plugins/firebase";

export const state = () => ({
  user: null
})

export const mutation = {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },

  SIGNOUT_USER(state) {
    state.user = null
  }
}

export const action = {
  async login ({ commit }, account) {
    const {email, password} = account

    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

    commit('SET_USER', auth.currentUser)
    this.$router.push('/admin')
  },

  async logout ({commit}) {
    await signOut(auth)
    commit('SIGNOUT_USER')
    this.$router.push('/')
  }
}
```

login.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="login">
        <div class="login__header">
          <div class="login__header--logo">
            <img src="/Logo.svg" alt="" class="login__header--logo__image" />
          </div>
          <h2 class="login__header--title">DASHBOARD</h2>
        </div>
        <form class="login__form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="form-group__label">E-Mail</label>
            <input
              v-model="email"
              type="email"
              autocomplete="email"
              class="form-control"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="form-group__label">Password</label>
            <input
              v-model="password"
              type="password"
              class="form-control"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="admin submit-btn" type="submit" @click.prevent="login()">SIGN-IN</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'LoginView',
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    login () {
      this.$store.dispatch("users/login", this.email, this.password);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found finally solution. I used action instead of actions. "S"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).